# how do I order a column by groups rather than numbers?

Tags: sql, db2

Hi I am using sql db2 to create age_bands as so:

```
case when age between 0 and 1 then '0-1'
when age between 2 and 3 then '2-3'
.
.
.
when age between 10 and 11 then '10-11'
```

which of course when you order you get the following:

```
0-1
10-11
2-3
```

which is not what i want. How do i order by the actual age_bands to get:

```
0-1
2-3
10-11
```

?

thanks very much.

Comment: If you really wanna do this, you can first locate your '-' sign in your new column with age range, then pick the left side number, in your case would be 0,2,10. Then convert those to int, and order by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this

```
ORDER BY age
```

Age is still ascending of course, even if the `age_bands` CASE expression is not

Comment: thanks - however this does order by age, but really i want the total per age group and not to have to create more fields for every different age within that group.

Comment: @brucezepplin: I don't understand that. You have age already for the CASE. Are you aggregating the data (eg COUNT) etc?

Answer (score 1):

Order by age is simplest, as already stated.

However if you need to assign a band number or code, or need totals or statistics by band, or some other sort within the band, then you may want to approach this differently.  You may want to have an AgeBand table, defining the age range, perhaps the band number or code, perhaps a name for the age band, or other "master" data.

If that is the case you would get your band code with a

```
left join AgeBand ab   on details.age >= ab.FromAge and details.age <= ab.ToAge
...
order by ab.BandID, ...
```

But if you don't need the AgeBand table, and would like to continue to compute the age band code with a CASE statement, that is fine too, and may be all you need.

What you can do is put your current query in a common table expression, or CTE, to prepare your data, then continue the SELECT statement, using the name you assigned to the CTE as your from-table.

```
WITH q AS
(SELECT ...
        CASE WHEN ...  THEN "00-01"
             WHEN ...  THEN "02-03"
             ...
             WHEN ...  THEN "10-11"
        END as bandcode
   FROM yourinputdata as i
   WHERE ...
)
SELECT bandcode, ...
  FROM q
  ORDER BY bandcode, ...
;
```

The WITH and the query between the quotes is the common table expression.  It is given a name "q" in the first line, and then referred to at the bottom.  It is the bottom full-select that controls your final results.

Comment: And if you add `GROUP BY bandcode` to the bottom SELECT is where you can get your group statistics with aggregate functions like count(), sum(), min(), max(), avg(), stddev(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to do:

```
order by min(age)
```